# How to verify fingerprint which is captured in mobile with Desktop captured fingerprint using SecuZen SDK

Tags: fingerprint

How to verify fingerprint which is captured in mobile with Desktop captured fingerprint using SecuZen SDK?. I can verify the fingers which both captured (using SecuZen Mobile SDK) in Mobile, but this fingers are not verifying With Desktop SDK (SecuZen) Please help me on this, If anyone knows .

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I did capturing , enrolling , template  creation for ANSI , ISO formats and i can verify it from mobile and sending the finger bytes  to the server through web service  , In desktop application getting the finger bytes from server ,capturing live finger in Desktop application and verifying it , but its not verifying

Comment: Then why don't you share relevant parts of your code here? So that people can help you.

Comment: You're sending bytes to the server through web service and getting bytes, there is a change to losing bytes. Can you try to send the ISO template as a base64 and retrieve it as a base64 then convert it to byte and after then verify by SDK?.